# kernel dead in using pytorch

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

The kernel crashes when I run a simple code using pytorch (even though it's not used here).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

When I run this code on Jupyter, it shows the kernel is dead. When I run it on Visual Code, it shows:

> Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
> The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.

How to resolve this issue. The torch package is supposed to be used later.

Comment: I guess you might have conflicts between different packages you installed. Try setting up a "fresh" environment, and see if this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by updating the numpy and matplotlib packages. These packages were installed just one year ago, though.